# How can I build packages manually, similar to `homebrew`?

Tags: homebrew

When I do a `brew install --build-from-source $FORMULA`, homebrew is able to build my package. When I take the same tar/gzip package (found in `/Library/Cache/Homebrew/`), decompress and follow the build instructions I get a whole bunch of compile errors.

I noticed that homebrew is using something called `superenv` but I'm not sure how to apply that to my manual build process. **How can I build my packages manually, similar to the way homebrew does?**

Comment: Which formula did you try with? FYI we (Homebrew) are working on reproducible builds, i.e. be clear about how we build stuff so anybody can reproduce any build and get the exact same result. This ensures nobody can change anything to the build process (e.g. add backdoors, etc) without triggering the alarm. Other folks like Debian are working on that too.

Comment: `phantomjs`. I'd be happy to show you a sample of the output. It looks like, when `homebrew` is working, it's able to find the header files it needs, but when I try to build outside of `homebrew`, my environment is set up in such a way that the build tools can't find the headers. Is there a way to see what environment `brew` is using to build?

Comment: You can find some docs here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/How-to-build-software-outside-Homebrew-with-Homebrew-keg-only-dependencies.md